# How to debug endpoint discovery in google nearby connections API on Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-nearby

I am trying to test google nearby connections API by writing a simple, single class android program. Unfortunately I am not able to connect to physical devices, after starting discovering and advertising.

All code is located within single class. App is written with *Kotlin* by almost directly copying the code from API [website](https://developers.google.com/nearby/connections/overview) and translating it from Java to Kotlin.
I don't know where to look for a problem. Logs doesn't seem to show any obvious results. 
I kept one phone advertising for more than a couple of minutes and the other one discovering meanwhile. Bluetooth is on, and both devices are in one WiFi network with Internet access. I use *Star* Strategy.
EndpointDiscoveryCallback is never called.

Here are my implementations of startDiscovery and endpointCallback

```
private fun startClient() {
    connClient.startDiscovery(deviceId, endpointDiscoveryCallback, discOptions)
        .addOnSuccessListener {
            Toast.makeText(
                applicationContext,
                "Discovering started",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
            currentStateTextView.text = "discovering"

        }.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            Toast.makeText(
                applicationContext,
                "Discovery failed, exception thrown: ${exception.message}.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        }
}


private val endpointDiscoveryCallback = object : EndpointDiscoveryCallback() {
    override fun onEndpointFound(endpointId: String, info: DiscoveredEndpointInfo) {
        connClient.requestConnection(deviceId, endpointId, connectionLifecycleCallback)
            .addOnSuccessListener {

            }
            .addOnFailureListener {

            }
    }

    override fun onEndpointLost(endpointId: String) {
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Endpoint: $endpointId lost!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show()
    }

}
```

I succeeded to connect the same decives using sample app "Rock, Paper, Scissors" which is based on the same API. Unfortunately, till now i cannot find the clue why the devices wont find each other with my code, and where to look for a hint.

Comment: You'll need to upload more code (or a link to a github project). I need to see the DiscoveryOptions, as well as what you're doing for startAdvertising.

Comment: Here's the github repo https://github.com/MiqeyM/QuizMiko/blob/testingAllMain/app/src/main/java/com/example/quizmiko/MainActivity.kt